# C++ executing a code from a text file

Tags: c++, compilation, interpreter

The title says it all. Like a compiler but not the same. I want a certain part of the code to be executed from an outer source in C++. And I don't know if that is even possible as it is in Javascript, Python etc.

Let's say I got a text file titled sample.txt like this:

```
int a = 10, c;
cin >> c;
cout << a + c;
```

And I'll call the text file in main() function and compiled the .exe file. When I run it, is it possible for it behave dynamically as if the code from the file is embedded in there and write 10 + input? The source file should be changed and different results will apply next time it runs. It's just an example piece of code by the way, I might want to run some for/while loops and if conditions etc.

PS: I know how to read from file and assign it as an integer or write it on the screen, that's not what I want. I need functions to be compiled through. Thanks.

Comment: The short answer is: nope. C++ does not work this way.

Comment: The long answer is: JavaScript and Python are interpreted languages while C/C++ are compiled.  You can check this source http://www.programiz.com/article/difference-compiler-interpreter for some explanation why it can't work :)

Comment: C++ is a compiled language not a scripting language. So no.

Comment: So everything compiler for c++ needs lots of assembly? C++ on its own cannot write its own compiler, right?

Comment: You want a language interpreter, as a library which you can include in your program.     Such things do exist but are very rare in C++, due to complexity of the language and library, and tend to implement a pretty small subset of the language (and even smaller subset of the library, which limits their utility).   Interpreters embedded in programs don't modify the executable that hosts them though - self-modifying executables are generally associated with malware.

Comment: I'm aware that it is a compiled language, that's why I stated that I need a compiler-like thing. JS and Python are for the sake of an example. I know the difference between a compiler and an interpreter, thank you for answers anyway. I'm creating a graphic library like Processing. You know it has its own language, written in Java, and can run native Java code combined with its own language as well. How is it working then?

Comment: If it is provided in library form, it is possible to embed the interpreter of another language into C++, e.g. [Lua](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#4), [Python](https://docs.python.org/3.5/extending/embedding.html) and [JavaScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript_engine). Your program can then pass code to be executed to the interpreter. Or if you just want to use C++ scripting you could consider using Cern's [cling](https://root.cern.ch/cling)

Comment: The gdb [compile](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Compiling-and-Injecting-Code.html) command can do this, but I don't know if there's a variant of its code that a program can run to alter itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A compiled C++ program contains only the machine instructions necessary to execute the compiled source code, the language standard does not specify any mechanism for the user to produce additional machine instructions at run time.

In order to provide a scripting capability - the ability to generate program flow in response to the parsing of input text - you have to provide a parser and an execution engine.

```
int main()
{
    std::string cmd;
    int op1, op2;
    while (cin >> cmd >> op1 >> op2) {
       if (cmd == "add")
           std::cout << op1 + op2 << "\n";
       else if (cmd == "sub")
           std::cout << op1 - op2 << "\n";
       else
           std::cerr << "error\n";
    }
}
```

Many interpreted languages are written in C or C++ in the first place, so it is often possible to build them as a library which you can then incorporate into an application so that the program can call invoke them to provide an embedded scripting language. Common examples of such languages are [Lua](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#4), [Python](https://docs.python.org/3.5/extending/embedding.html) and [JavaScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript_engine). Your program can then pass code to be executed to the interpreter.

Writing your own lua interpreter could look like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <lua.h>
#include <lauxlib.h>
#include <lualib.h>

bool get_input(std::string& in)
{
  bool result;
  do {
    std::cout << "lua> " << std::flush;
    result = std::getline(std::cin, in);
  } while (result && in.empty());
  return result;
}

int main (void) {
  lua_State *L = lua_open();   // open lua
  luaL_openlibs(L);            // open standard libraries

  std::string in;
  while (get_input(in)) {
    if (in.empty())
        continue;

    int error = luaL_loadbuffer(L, in.c_str(), in.size(), "line") ||
                lua_pcall(L, 0, 0, 0); 
    if (error) {
      std::cerr << lua_tostring(L, -1) << '\n';
      lua_pop(L, 1);  // remove the error message from the stack
    }
  }

  lua_close(L);
}
```

Under linux:

```
$ g++ -Wall -O3 -o mylua mylua.cpp -I/usr/include/lua5.1 -llua
$ ./mylua
lua> print("hello")
hello
lua> error
[string "line"]:1: '=' expected near '<eof>'
lua>
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of approaches to this.

### Fork a command-line compiler and the fork to run the result, passing input and output through STDIN/STDOUT

(While i realize you asked for this from a C++ calling program, i'm demonstrating the idea in bash for simplicity.)

File: `run_it.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e  # Bail on the first error

FN_IN=./sample.txt
FN_WRAPPED=./wrapped.cc
FN_EXE=./wrapped
CC=g++

# Wrap the fragment in a full C++ program and compile it.
function build_wrapper () {
  cat > $FN_WRAPPED <<'EOF'
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
EOF
  cat $FN_IN >> $FN_WRAPPED 
  cat >> $FN_WRAPPED <<'EOF'
return 0;
}
EOF
  $CC -o $FN_EXE $FN_WRAPPED 
}

# Run the wrapper, passing input through STDIN and reading the output from STDOUT.
function run () {
  local IN=$1
  echo $IN | $FN_EXE
}

# Remove the wrapper (both code and compiled).
function clean_up () {
  rm -f $FN_WRAPPED $FN_EXE
}

build_wrapper

IN=24
OUT=$(echo "$IN" | $FN_EXE)
echo "Result = $OUT"

echo "Another result = $(run 16)"

clean_up
```

`$ ./run_it.sh`

```
Result = 34
Another result = 26
```

### Use something like LLVM to compile the function in-process and call it

This approach is very powerful, but also somewhat involved.

In a nutshell, you'd want to

1. Read `sample.txt` into memory.
2. Compile it to a function.
3. Call the function.

Some possibly-helpful links:

- http://fdiv.net/2012/08/15/compiling-code-clang-api
- http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-createcompilerllvm1/
- http://llvm.org/docs/tutorial/
- https://msm.runhello.com/p/1003
- https://db.in.tum.de/teaching/ss15/moderndbs/resources/7/fibonacci.cpp